# How to read pdf images as opencv images using PyMuPDF?

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv, pymupdf

I would like to read all images found in a `pdf` file by `PyMuPDF` as `opencv` images, as close as they are from the source (avoiding funky format conversions that would lead to precision loss). Basically, **I would like the result to be the exact same as if I was doing a `cv2.imread(filename):`** (in terms of the type it outputs, color space, etc...)

```
# Libraries
import os
import cv2
import fitz
import numpy as np

# Input file
filename = "myfile.pdf"

# Read all images in file as a list of opencv images
def read_images(filename):
    images = []:
    _, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    # If it's a pdf process each image
    if (extension == ".pdf"):
        pdf = fitz.open(file)
        for index in range(len(pdf)):
            page = pdf[index]
            for im in page.getImageList():
                xref = im[0]
                pix = fitz.Pixmap(pdf, xref)
                images.append(pix_to_opencv_image(pix)) # DO SOMETHING HERE
    # Otherwise just do an imread 
    else:
        images.append(cv2.imread(filename))
    return images
```

Basically I would like to know what the function `pix_to_opencv_image` should be:

```
# Equivalent of doing a "cv2.imread" on a pdf pixmap:
def pix_to_opencv_image(pix):
    # DO SOMETHING HERE
```

If found example explaining how to convert pdf pixmaps to numpy arrays, but nothing that outputs an opencv image.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: try `np.asarray(the_pixmap.samples_mv)` and see what .shape that has. I'm betting `(width*height*nchannels, )` so you only have to reshape that using some other properties of the pixmap object -- if that didn't work, call `.tobytes()` to get the file data, then turn that into a numpy array, then you can use `cv.imdecode` --

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `help()` function to find the various data descriptors associated with it `-->` `help(pix)`

`pix.samples` stores the image information as bytes. Using `numpy`'s `frombuffer`, the image array can be obtained from these bytes after reshaping accordingly.

`pix.height` and `pix.width` gives the height and width of the image array respectively. `pix.n` is the number of channels. These can be used for reshaping the resulting array.

Your complete function would be:

```
def pix_to_image(pix):
    bytes = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8)
    img = bytes.reshape(pix.height, pix.width, pix.n)
    return img
```

You can display the result using `cv2.imshow()`.

Comment: you need to convert the `img` from RGB to BGR before using in `cv2.imshow()` using the method `cv2.cvtColor()` for the image to retain its original color